# SonarQube - Analyse JSON File

Tags: json, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

Is it possible to analyse a `json` file with SonarQube? (I don't mean to analyse the format properties, I want to analyse a value in this file and trigger a rule if this value is greater than some threshold)

If this is possible I'm interested in how one could do this with a custom SonarQube plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like SonarQube does not support a built-in functionality to analyse the content of `json` files. However according to [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/need-to-analyse-json-file-with-sonarqube/29138) it seems like there is a [github plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-json-plugin) which should do the job.